# Override horizontally compact environment behaviour for modalPresentationStyle of '.formSheet'

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, size-classes

When presenting a UIViewController with `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet`, Horizontally compact environment behaves same as `UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen`

According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/formsheet)

> **UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet.**
>   In a horizontally regular environment, the view controller is sized so that its content area is smaller than the screen size and a dimming view is placed underneath the content. If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so that the view remains visible. All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.
>   In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen.

It looks like Apple Maps settings screen is presented with `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet` but for Horizontally compact environment, it doesn't cover fullscreen but it covers only half the screen.

[image: Settings on Apple Map]

How can we override the behaviour for Horizontally Compact environment so that it covers only the half of the screen?

Comment: Did you manage to implement this? I'm looking for the same

Comment: I solved it with autolayout by checking size classes manually.. listen for traitCollectionDidChange and update the layoutContraints

Comment: In my case, it's a popover, not an actionsheet. I tried to implement `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` protocol too and say it should switch modelPresentation style when traitCollection change like this  `(if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
      return .custom
    } else {
      return .popover
    }) `, but it is not working.... following is my question, if you can provide an answer I really appreciate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858550/avoid-popover-adapting-to-fullscreen-in-horizontally-compact-environment