# Avoid popover adapting to fullscreen in horizontally compact environment

Tags: ios, swift, popover

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html),

> In a horizontally compact environment, popovers adapt to the
> UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen presentation style by default.

See below image. In compact environment, popover appear from bottom and animate to top until it covers the entire screen.

[image]

Is it possible to override this behaviour and have the popover only covering certain height of the screen as shown below?

[image]

Following code demonstrate the default behaviour of popover adapting to FullScreen presentation style in compact environment.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.2x2.fill"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(displayPopover), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        ])
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func displayPopover(sender: UIButton!) {
        let popoverVC = PopoverViewController()
        popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        self.present(popoverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
}

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This feature is now available with iOS 15.**

Watch WWDC2021 short [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10063/)

Download WWDC sample project from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/customize_and_resize_sheets_in_uikit)

```
 @IBAction func showImagePicker(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    if let popover = imagePicker.popoverPresentationController {
        popover.barButtonItem = sender
        
        let sheet = popover.adaptiveSheetPresentationController
        sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
        sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
        sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
        sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true 
        sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
    }
    
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```